# Is it possible in heroku to return the list of backups for the app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

I found out that Heroku::Client::Pgbackups is already deprecated so I'm wondering if it's possible to run in Ruby a command to execute "heroku pgbackups" with using only the heroku-api gem.

I'm trying to make a maintenance site for my heroku apps. Just list down all the apps, and on just a click of a button, I can view the list of backups and can also revert/download backups from the list.

Most of the CLI processes are already available in the gem, except for listing backups. Is there any way to do it aside from doing a system() command? Because I might host my app on a server w/o heroku toolbelt installed. That way, my app can only connect via the api using heroku-api gem.

I know this asks too much, but if you can provide me something to work on that would be pretty much be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

turns out that it's possible to do this to get the backup:

```
api = Heroku::API.new(:api_key => your_api_key)  
pgbackups_url = api.get_config_vars('app_name').body['PGBACKUPS_URL']
client = Heroku::Client::Pgbackups.new pgbackups_url
client.get_backups
```

then it returns the list of the backups. So awesome!
For more pgbackups functions, check it here: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/master/lib/heroku/client/pgbackups.rb

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups#list-backups

```
$ heroku pgbackups
ID   | Backup Time         | Size  | Database
-----+---------------------+-------+------------------------
a226 | 2012/02/22 20:02.19 | 5.3KB | DATABASE_URL
a227 | 2012/02/23 20:02.19 | 5.3KB | DATABASE_URL
b251 | 2012/02/24 16:08.02 | 5.3KB | HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLACK
b252 | 2012/02/24 16:08.53 | 5.3KB | HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PINK
```